# Android result of a method as a static property

Tags: android

Will the code below be effective? I mean, will it actually be run just one and the result will be cached in the property, so the next call will not re-run the method anymore?

```
public static final String LOG_TAG = MyApplication.getContext().getApplicationInfo().name;
```

Somehow I cannot find it anywhere.

comment.

Since you guys seem to focus on not important things, here's the changed code:

```
public static final String SomeVar = MyApplication.someMethod();
```

Comment: Since you're hardcoding a string value... why not use something you wanna monitor? Like class name? why automate this?

it's a debug tag, use it crudely as you should :)

Comment: Is that the point of the question?

Comment: the method will be called only once ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that, since `Application.getContext()` method isn't `static`.

**EDIT:** I see you edited your question: So if your `MyApplication.someMethod()` method is `static`, than ofcourse it works, and `someMethod()` will be only called once, unless your class gets destroyed and recreated by the garbage collector.

Comment: It is possible. I made this method as static in MyApplication inheriting from Application. But it doesn't matter.

Comment: Pretty obvious answer, need more coffee.Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure. I usually get it this way:

My(Activity)Class.class.getSimpleName();